# 2 strings return distinct common words in order

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here are the 2 strings:

```
firstText = 'I LoVe LOVE You'

secondText = 'Love is a cool feeling love you too'
```

the return should be `['LoVe','You']`

but I could only get `['Love','LOVE','You']`

```
list = []

i = 0
for words in firstText.casefold().split():
    if words in secondText.casefold().split():
        i += 1

    if words not in list:
        list.append(firstText.split()[i])
print(list)
```

Comment: Think about what you're adding to `list` here, and thus what you're comparing when you do `words not in list`.

Comment: Also, please don't use the name `list` for your variable. It shadows the built-in type `list`.

Comment: A simpler way would be to use `set` intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple adjustment to your code to obtain the result you wanted:

```
firstText = 'I LoVe LOVE You'

secondText = 'Love is a cool feeling love you too'

words_list = []

i = 0
for word in firstText.upper().split():
    if word in secondText.upper().split():
        if word not in " ".join(words_list).upper():
            words_list.append(firstText.split()[i])
    i += 1

print(words_list)
```

The problem was that you were comparing string with different case formats (LoVe and LOVE for exemple), so the comparison didn't match. Here I uppercase all the saved words before the comparaison. By doing so I compared things that could be compared together.

If you want any other insight let me know.